# When is holomorphic the same as analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

I'm basing this question on some asumptions: first, that there are multiple "places" where one can "do" analysis (such as $\mathbb{R}$,\mathbb{C}, $p$-adic numbers, maybe Banach/Hilbert spaces) and second, that it is possible to define holomorphic and analytic functions.

In every such place (what would a precise definition be?) it is expected that analytic$\Rightarrow$holomorphic, so when and where is the converse true? If we are working in $\mathbb{C}$ we can, so what makes it special?

Sorry for the very non-rigorous question, hopefully it is understood what king of answer I expect

Thanks!

Comment: $C^{\infty}$ functions are usually called *smooth*. Holomorphic normally means $\partial f/ \partial \bar{z} = 0$, or an equivalent generalisation.

Comment: On $\mathbf C$, both notions are equivalent.

Comment: To perhaps clarify the prior comments, the term "holomorphic" is usually reserved only for $\mathbb C$ where it refers to something that is complex differentiable (or, equivalently, satisfies the CR equations as given by Chappers above) in which case it turns out to be equivalent to the idea of being expressed locally via a power series, i.e. being analytic. There is an easy generalization of the CR equations to $\mathbb C^n$ and we can get complex manifolds from this, but outside of things fundamentally based on $\mathbb C$ you must first define what "holomorphic" means